# Como usar o "EXPLORE" para filtrar um determinado grupo de URLs pelo path da aplicação que tenho mapeado com o swagger?

Tags: java, spring-boot, yaml

```
springdoc:
  api-docs:
    path: /api-general
  swagger-ui:
    path: /api-docs/swagger-ui
  paths-to-match:
 - /api/**
 - /api/a/**
 - /api/b/**
 - /api/c/**
```

Só está carregando se eu altero nesse documento, deixando apenas `/api/a` , ou `/api/b` etc...  Queria que no filtro do explorer eu pudesse filtrar o tipo do controller que estou chamando na API, é possível?

[Documentação do swagger](https://swagger.io/docs/)